# G'MIC library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image-processing, gmic

Does the G'MIC (Grey's Magic Image Converter) library work on iOS ?

what steps i should take in order to begin adapting it?

this is library link  http://gmic.sourceforge.net/gimp.shtml

Comment: lobrary link:http://gmic.sourceforge.net/gimp.shtml

Comment: What language is this thing written in?

Comment: it was written using c++

Comment: Then it should have no problem running on an iOS device.  You could even write a thin ObjC++ wrapper for it to make your life a bit easier, but in it's current form, it should work smashingly.

Comment: Basically i need this library to do a cartoons effects on images within iPhone application

Comment: I'll put my comment up as the answer so you can accept it and this thing doesn't wind up in the unanswered column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as it's written in C++, it should have no problem running on an iOS device. You could even write a thin ObjC++ wrapper for it to make your life a bit easier, but in it's current form, it should work smashingly.

Comment: Regarding the double post, did you open a bug report?

Comment: No, I did not.  Is there any way to more permanently delete it?